# Is the Mecha-Godzilla pilot (Ren Serizawa) related to Dr. Ishiro Serizawa?

Tags: character-identification, monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

In *Godzilla vs. Kong (2021)* movie, Walter Simmons introduces the character played by Shun Oguri as Ren Serizawa:

> **Walter**: Walt Simmons.
>
> **Nathan**: I know who you are, sir. It’s an honor.
>
> **Walter**: No, the honor is mine. As is the urgency. Godzilla has never attacked us unprovoked before. These are dangerous times, Dr. Lind. Allow me to introduce our Apex chief technology officer, ***Mr. Ren Serizawa***. He has an interesting thing to show you.

The fact that his name was mentioned just once in the entire movie was quite surprising. However his last name did catch my attention.

In the two previous Godzilla movies, Ken Watanabe played the role of Dr. Ishiro Serizawa (who sacrifices himself in *Godzilla: King of Monsters* to revive Godzilla).

A fan theory I read somewhere suggested that Ren is the son of the deceased Dr. Ishiro.

Is this theory true or the fact the Ren had the same the last name as Dr. Ishiro merely a coincidence?

Comment: I see that thinks like these are merely a coincidence in Science Fiction. Why create a confusion among audience if you can just choose any other name ?

Comment: @atakanyenel a coincidence that the writers choose one name out of a possible tens of thousands of names? and that happened to be one of the main character from the previous movies? the odds are astronomical!

Comment: Yes, we are arguing the same thing :) probably I should have said ,hardly a coincidence , instead of , merely a coincidence. My bad...

Comment: @atakanyenel one word changed the whole meaning and I too got confused  ‍♂️ my bad as well ‍♂️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ren is Ishiro's son.**

> Of course, his grandfather Eiji had set the pattern. A sailor in World
> War II, he had lied to his son Ishiro for thirty-five years, claiming
> to work for a cargo company when in fact he had been drawn into
> working for Monarch. Eiji had come clean to his son, before he died in
> 1981, and they had had at least a little time to reconcile, for father
> to pass the torch to son.
>
> But he would never get any such catharsis. His father had all but
> ignored him in life, but **Ren had worshipped Ishiro, nonetheless. He
> had studied hard, learned to build and create in hopes that his father
> would someday understand him—or at least take note of him.** It was on
> Gojira that Ren focused his anger. Gojira had felt almost like a big
> brother to him—the older brother his father truly loved and doted on.
> And in the end, his father had died for Gojira—a monster who had
> killed thousands—rather than come home alive to his only son.
>
> <sub><sup>[Godzilla vs. Kong: The Official Movie Novelization](https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Kong:_The_Official_Movie_Novelization)</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks @V. Well I thought there would be something in the Official novelization but I couldn't find one with free access.